# Only the first test passes with TestScheduler when running multiple tests (Kotlin)

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to test my presenter in an MVP architecture using RxJava in Kotlin. I have created a test rule to substitute the usual schedulers with a `TestScheduler` to be able to test asynchronous requests:

```
class TestSchedulerRule : TestRule {

    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    override fun apply(base: Statement, d: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
                RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }
                RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { testScheduler }

                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    RxJavaPlugins.reset()
                    RxAndroidPlugins.reset()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test class. The problem is that every test is passing, if I run them separately, but if I run the whole suite, only the first one passes. There should be a problem with the `TestScheduler`, because if I use an immediate scheduler, it works.

```
class UserListPresenterTest {

    @Rule @JvmField
    val testSchedulerRule = TestSchedulerRule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockGetUsers: GetUsers

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockView: UserListView

    lateinit var userListPresenter: UserListPresenter

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        userListPresenter = UserListPresenter(mockGetUsers)
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetUsers_errorCase_showError() {
        // Given
        val error = "Test error"
        val single: Single<List<UserViewModel>> = Single.create {
            emitter -> emitter?.onError(Exception(error))
        }

        // When
        `when`(mockGetUsers.execute(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(single)

        userListPresenter.attachView(mockView)
        userListPresenter.getUsers()

        testSchedulerRule.testScheduler.triggerActions()

        // Then
        verify(mockView).hideLoading()
        verify(mockView).showError()
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetUsers_successCaseFirstPage_clearList() {
        // Given
        val users = listOf(UserViewModel(1, "Name", 1000, ""))
        val single: Single<List<UserViewModel>> = Single.create {
            emitter -> emitter?.onSuccess(users)
        }

        // When
        `when`(mockGetUsers.execute(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyBoolean())).thenReturn(single)

        userListPresenter.attachView(mockView)
        userListPresenter.getUsers()

        testSchedulerRule.testScheduler.triggerActions()

        // Then
        verify(mockView).clearList()
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get in the console:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mockView.hideLoading();
-> at com.example.tamaskozmer.kotlinrxexample.UserListPresenterTest.testGetUsers_errorCase_showError(UserListPresenterTest.kt:57)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.example.tamaskozmer.kotlinrxexample.UserListPresenterTest.testGetUsers_errorCase_showError(UserListPresenterTest.kt:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at com.example.tamaskozmer.kotlinrxexample.TestSchedulerRule$apply$1.evaluate(TestSchedulerRule.kt:28)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

UserListPresenter class

```
class UserListPresenter(private val getUsers: GetUsers) : BasePresenter<UserListView>() {

    private val offset = 5

    private var page = 1
    private var loading = false

    fun getUsers(forced: Boolean = false) {
        loading = true
        if (forced) {
            resetPaging()
        }
        getUsers.execute(page, forced)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    users ->
                    loading = false
                    if (page == 1) {
                        view?.clearList()
                    }
                    view?.addUsersToList(users)
                    view?.hideLoading()
                    page++
                },
                {
                    loading = false
                    view?.showError()
                    view?.hideLoading()
                })
    }

    private fun resetPaging() {
        page = 1
    }

    fun onScrollChanged(lastVisibleItemPosition: Int, totalItemCount: Int) {
        if (!loading) {
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount - offset) {
                getUsers()
            }
        }

        if (loading && lastVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount) {
            view?.showLoading()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The init hooks affect the first creation of the Schedulers class and thus can't be reset. You should override the dynamic `setComputationSchedulerHandler` and co instead.

Comment: I tried to do that first, but that way I couldn't even run the tests separately. I got this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers`

Comment: Yeah, AndroidSchedulers is a different animal. Keep that as `RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler` but have the rest as I suggested.

Comment: Just tried it. It produces the same results, only the first test passes.

Comment: What is the error stacktrace, including the error type? (Your post cut out the exception type)

Comment: There could be something in `UserListPresenter` that doesn't get set up properly. Can you somehow share the code?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: Nothing stands out beyond the showError and hideLoading being swapped in the code and in the unit test. I'd start debugging by placing breakpoints on `emitter?.onError(Exception(error))` and following the emission. You can add `doOnEvent()` at various places to see where the code stops. Also you can try and call `triggerActions` again or replace it with `advanceTimeBy` just in case.

Comment: I faced the same issue, did you figure out so far?

Answer (score 2):

Just fixed same issue. You should define your schedulers ones and not specify them in the rule. RxAndroidPlugins will keep the first instance of TestScheduler after TestRule.apply will put another instance for a new test.

Putting setting scheduler handlers in companion objects will help

```
companion object {

    val testScheduler: TestScheduler

    init {
        testScheduler = TestScheduler()
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { _ -> testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler { _ -> testScheduler }
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler { _ -> testScheduler }

    }
}
```